# Creating a simple language translator

Tags: php, html, arrays, forms

I'm trying to create a very simple language translator using PHP and a html form. My goal is to for the user to type whatever word he/she wants to be translated into the language chosen through the radio button. Example: They type the swedish word "Smultron" and choses the language they want through the radio buttons, and then when they hit submit the translation shows up.

My code looks like this so far:

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['submit']))

$swedish = array('päron', 'apelsin', 'jordgubbe', 'ananas', 'citron', 'smultron', 'hallon', 'körsbär', 'drakfrukt', 'blåbär');
$english = array('pear', 'orange', 'strawberry', 'pineapple', 'lemon', 'wild strawberry', 'raspberry', 'cherry', 'dragon fruit', 'blueberry');
$french = array('poire', 'orange', 'fraise', 'ananas', 'citron', 'fraises sauvages', 'framboises', 'cerises', 'fruit du dragon', 'myrtille');
$spanish = array('peras', 'naranja', 'fresa', 'piña', 'limón', 'fresas silvestres', 'frambuesas', 'cerezas', 'pitaya', 'arándanos');
$russian = array('груши', 'оранжевый', 'клубника', 'ананас', 'лимон', 'земляника', 'малина', 'вишня', 'плод дракона', 'черника');
$german = array('birnen', 'orange', 'Erdbeere', 'ananas', 'Zitrone', 'Walderdbeeren', 'Himbeeren', 'Kirschen', 'Drachenfrucht', 'Blaubeeren');
?>

<html>
    <body>
            <form action="index.php" method="POST">
                <p>Översättaren</p> <input type="text" name="text" /><br />
                Engelska: <input type="radio" name="radio" value="english"/>
                Spanska: <input type="radio" name="radio" value="spanish"/>
                Tyska: <input type="radio" name="radio" value="german"/>
                Ryska: <input type="radio" name="radio" value="russian"/>
                Franska: <input type="radio" name="radio" value="french"/> <br />
                <input type="submit" name ="submit"
                />
            </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

I'm stuck and I have not been able to find any answers on the subject PHP with HTML-forms and radio buttons on google/in my PHP-book. Swedish translation is not needed.

Is there anyone out there who can help me with these simple lines of codes? Much appreciated.

Comment: Why not just integrate with something like a Google Translate API, that way you're not limited to only translating a dozen or so words?

Comment: That's not needed. In my assignment we were given 10 swedish words to translate into five other languages. But I can definitely agree with you that the API would be a much more efficient approach!

Comment: `"In my assignment"` - Homework then, got it.  In that case, where are you stuck?  Currently this question reads like, "Here's what I need to do, show me everything I need in order to do it."  Stack Overflow doesn't really work like that.  What have you tried and where are you stuck?  What's your next step?  What isn't working as expected?

Comment: Well, unfortunately yes. I'm sorry, it's the first time I'm using this site. It feels like I'm stuck trying to figure out how to get the text input the user provides to cooperate with the radio button (language provided) and the submit button. I want to create the code that takes the text provided, searches for the language in the correct array and then echoes out the translation underneath the form in a way like "The spanish translation is = pitaya".

Comment: Well, your code is already checking a form value here: `$_POST['submit']`  Other form values would come in the same way, as part of the `$_POST` collection.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using [MyMemory API](http://mymemory.translated.net/doc/spec.php).

```
<?php
      $url="http://api.mymemory.translated.net/get?q=".$_POST['yourword']."&langpair=sv|".$_POST['languagecode'];
      $result = file_get_contents($url);
      $obj=json_decode($result);
      $obj=$obj->{'responseData'};
      echo $obj->{'translatedText'};
?>
```

For example:

`$_POST['yourword'] -> Hej` & `$_POST['languagecode'] -> it`

"Ciao" is going to be the echo...